# Transaction Promise Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to dynamically create a `Peer` (participant) through a transaction `enrollPeer`. I want the chaincode to generate the peerIDs on its own by getting `num of peers` and adding 1.

I am getting a timeout when I let the chaincode create a peerID on it's own. When I pass the `peerID` in the transaction (optional field), it sucessfully gets added to the registry. Is there a problem with how I am resolving my promises?

```
function enrollNewPeer(enroll){
    var factory = getFactory();
    var NS = 'org.acme.destro';

    if(enroll.typeOfPeer == null){
        enroll.typeOfPeer = 'Peer';
    }

    /* Make sure type exists */
    enroll.typeOfPeer = 'Peer';
    /* Make sure peerID does not exist */
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Peer')
    .then(function (peerRegistry) {            
        return peerRegistry.exists(enroll.peerID);  
    }).then(function (assetFound) {
        if (assetFound) {
            throw new Error("Peer Already Exitsts");
        }
        if(enroll.peerID == null){
            getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Peer')
            .then(function (peerRegistry) {            
                return peerRegistry.getAll(); //returns list of Peers
            }).then(function(allPeers){ 
                var peerNum = (allPeers.length) + 1; // get #of peers and add 1
                var event = factory.newEvent(NS,'numPeers');
                event.peers = peerNum;
                emit(event);
            }).then(function() {
                enroll.peerID = 'peer' + peerNum;
            });
        }
    }).then(function() {
        var peer = factory.newResource(NS, enroll.typeOfPeer, enroll.peerID);
        peer.peerPubKey = assignKey(peer.peerID);

        var event = factory.newEvent(NS,'newPeer');
        event.peer = peer;
        emit(event);

        return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.' + enroll.typeOfPeer)
        .then(function(participantRegistry) {
            return participantRegistry.add(peer);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: for a start, there's nothing returned in `.then(function (assetFound) {` - so the following `.then` won't "wait" for the promise returned by `getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Peer')`

Comment: The return in `.then(function (assetFound) {` isn't implicit?

I'm a noob at node, what would I need to do for the promise to wait?

Comment: yes, but it's the code in the **next** `.then` that I was referring to

Comment: So I need something like?
`return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Peer')`
inside of the `if(enroll.peerID == null){`

Comment: yes, exactly what I was going to suggest

Comment: I'm still getting a `timeout` :(

Comment: I don't actually understand how/where a `timeout` could occur in this code - any more useful information about this `timeout`? a stack trace? some useful information perhaps?

Comment: The rest server is issuing the timeout error 
**{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"Error trying invoke chaincode. Error: Error executing chaincode: Failed to execute transaction (Timeout expired while executing transaction)","stack":"Error: Error trying invoke chaincode. Error: Error executing chaincode: Failed to execute transaction (Timeout expired while executing transaction)\n    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:863:34)"}}**

Comment: so, the timeout is happening on the server - interesting

Comment: Decided to just make the peerID the transaction id if not provided, scales much better than polling the # of peers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to get the number of peers and then add 1 is likely to fail once you run across multiple peers in a true distributed network. Each Fabric peer is going to query the number of peers and there's likely to be a race-condition where different peers get different values -- causing the transaction to get rolled back due to consensus failure. You should allocate the "new peer ID" on the client and pass it in with the transaction - this will ensure that all Fabric peers use the same id.